# How to draw with mouse over webcam in Tkinter?

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter, drawing

I have an app that displays the webcam using OpenCV then this is converted to Tkinter (for GUI purposes). I can implement a mouse drawing function but the image update loop keeps covering it. I have tried raise/lower on canvas and labels but to no avail. Anyone got any ideas on this please?

Update Loop:

```
    def update(self):
        isTrue, frame = self.vid.getFrame()

        #Convert frame to TK and put on canvas
        if isTrue:
            self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=PIL.Image.fromarray(frame))
            self.image = self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=self.photo, anchor=tk.NW)

        self.window.after(10, self.update)
```

Draw Function:

```
    def paint(self, event):
        white = (255, 255, 255)
        x1, y1 = (event.x - 2), (event.y - 2)
        x2, y2 = (event.x + 2), (event.y + 2)
        self.canvas.create_oval(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill="white", outline="white")
```

Comment: Instead of creating new images each time, use `<tk.Canvas>.itemconfig(<object id>, image=...)`. That way you can always draw over the images.

Comment: Hi @TheLizzard! Could you give an example please? I have never used itemconfig.

Comment: Ad soon as you create the canvas, use `self.image = self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor="nw")`. Then after the `self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(...)`, use `self.canvas.itemconfig(self.image, image=self.photo)`.

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much, been trying to solve this for weeks. Still trying to get my head around the logic :-)

Comment: Basically you create 1 image and then re-configure it with a new sprite each time `update` runs. Because it was the first object to be created on the canvas it will be lowest so you don't have to worry about it going on top of other sprites.